# My UITableView won't scroll down through the end of the data! Why?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, scroll, datasource

Ok I don't know why this isn't working, but I have hooked up a tableView, with 19 items of text I'd like to set to each cell.

The cells populate just fine, but when I try and scroll, it goes down there and I can see the cells that aren't visible on the initial view, it hangs, and won't scroll down. It just snaps back. REALLY WEIRD!

What am I doing wrong?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section    {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return 19;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...
if(indexPath.row == 0){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 1){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 2){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 3){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 4){
    cell.indentationLevel = 2;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 5){
    cell.indentationLevel = 2;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 6){
    cell.indentationLevel = 2;      
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 7){
    cell.indentationLevel = 2;      
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 8){
    cell.indentationLevel = 2;      
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 9){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 10){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 11){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 12){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 13){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 14){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 15){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 16){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 17){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 18){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: All your cells are empty string text labels. Are you really sure you are not scrolling correctly and just can't tell because all the cells look alike?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

***Decrease*** your tableView's ***height***.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem. I have tried reducing the size of my table view but it still wouldn't scroll to the bottom and just scrolls back up to the first cell/top of the table view.

Comment: I think one of the following things cause this issue. 1. Height of the table extends beyond the height of the device. 2. Some other UI element is overlapping the bottom of your table. 3. Changes were made to the table data since the last time it was loaded.

Answer (score 9):

I know it's an old question and this is **not an answer** to your question, but a **suggestion to improve** your code so others can benefit.

**You could write this:**

```
if (indexPath.row >= 4 && indexPath.row <= 8) { // 4 and 8 inclusive
    cell.indentationLevel = 2;
}
cell.textLabel.text = @"";
```

**Instead of this:**

```
if(indexPath.row == 0){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 1){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 2){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 3){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 4){
    cell.indentationLevel = 2;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 5){
    cell.indentationLevel = 2;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 6){
    cell.indentationLevel = 2;      
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 7){
    cell.indentationLevel = 2;      
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 8){
    cell.indentationLevel = 2;      
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 9){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 10){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 11){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 12){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 13){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 14){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 15){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 16){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 17){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 18){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}
```

And if you happen to have different text for each case you could either use:

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"";
        break;
        ...
    case 18:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"";
    default:
        break;
}
```

Or even better to put everything inside an `NSArray` (database...) and just loop through them by the index.

Answer (score 6):

This helped me:

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,65,0)];
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: After altering my tableview to use a header cell from an xib I was getting the scroll problem.  This solved my problem but Im skeptical of the problems it might cause down stream. There must be something else going on...

Answer (score 4):

The code that you shared looks fine to me. Are you pushing view controller with this tableview on navigation controller stack ? I have seen people do that before. Default height of cell is 44px and height of navigation bar is 44px as well. So, if you push this on navigation controller stack you scroll view snaps back like you have described. If that is the case reduce height of TableView by 44 px ( in Interface builder or Programatically if you drew this programatically) and it should fix it.

Comment: In fact I believe this is the true answer. Just of course the self frame is including the navigation bar. And it can be retrieved I guess by UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height + (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)

Comment: Also it is an issue by rotation, the heights and widths are not automatically set right.

Comment: Use constraints in cases like this looks to be the only really working way in iOS. Using constraints the lists scrolls to the end.

Answer (score 4):

@EmptyStack answer is right.That was a alternate but NOT the Solution.

Even we can achieve the same in storyboard.

Select tableView --> from the storyboard control click on 'add Missing constraints'.
That will add the constraint to tableView and View.

That helped me to resolve this issue.
A screen_shot attached for reference.[image: solution]

Comment: Keep in mind that "Add Missing Constraints" can add constraints to margins, which aren't supported on older versions than ios8.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a storyboard or nib try this (note, you might have to add some constraints if you want to support landscape).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

Check the number of the row that you can't see.

After in your viewDidLoad, add this method:

```
myTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0,bottom: yourCellHeight * rowHeight,right: 0)
```

I hope I have been helpful

Answer (score 1):

You need to either adjust the height of you UITableView or you can try to put [tableView reloadData] inside viewDidAppear method (it doesn't seem to work if put inside viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad though).

The former works for me in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled automatic estimate and it help me.

[image: Disable Auto estimate]

Answer (score 0):

I solved last cell doesn't appear scrolling problem by setting bottom constraint of the tableview to be equal to safe area bottom

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).