# iOS - UITableView not scrolling to bottom

Tags: ios, uitableview, header, scroll, scrollto

I am building a chat app in iOS but I have some problems with the UITableView displaying all the messages. I want the table view to be scrolled to the bottom on load so users can see the latest messages when they open the app.

To do this I added this code in my function refreshing the data:

```
    NSIndexPath* ipath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: [self.messageOnTimeline numberOfRowsInSection:0]-1 inSection: 0];
    [self.messageOnTimeline scrollToRowAtIndexPath: ipath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated: YES];
```

This worked fine until I added a header to the tableview. I added the following code and now it doesn't scroll to the bottom when I load the app:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 30)];
    return view;
}
```

Does anyone knows why?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this code in you `viewDidload` :

**Swift 5**

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: <Row Index>, section: <Section Index>)
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

**Objective C**

```
NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:AddYourLastIndex inSection:0];
[self.tbl_presentation selectRowAtIndexPath:myIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
```

Answer (score 3):

try this code.it will scroll to bottom of tableview

```
 [self.tableview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.tableview.contentSize.height-self.tableview.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

@Darshan Kunjadiya answer is right.
 Even we can achieve the same in storyboard.

Select tableView --> from the storyboard control click on 'add Missing constraints'. That will add the constraint to tableView and View.

That helped me to resolve this issue. A screen_shot attached for reference.
[screen_shot Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272382/my-uitableview-wont-scroll-down-through-the-end-of-the-data-why/24991512#24991512)